# Using values from one table to be column names in a view

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables

Table 1 (all Int): `ID, SomeValue, Category, Dept`

Table 2: `CategoryID, VarChar CategoryName`

There's about 14 categories.

Now I need a view thats something like `DeptID, Cat1, Cat2, Cat3....Cat14`

A sample row would be: Music, 1, 4, 55, 6, 3....

So basically each dept has its own row that shows all the values from Table 1 that use that dept.
I also need the column names generated by Table 2 I think thats where I am lost.

How do I do this?

Comment: So I realized that I need something like pivot tables and am heading in a different direction now. I normalized too much in that it would take a lot more queries to show the data I need than to just pull some data back into the main table.

Comment: Difficulty in querying and performnce is why you should not use an EAV design to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a pivot using `group_concat`

```
SELECT 
  dept.id as dept_id
  dept.name as dept_name
  , group_concat(cat.CategoryName) as cat_names
FROM table1 as dept
INNER JOIN table2 as cat ON (dept.category = cat.category_id)
GROUP BY dept.id
```

Because it is MySQL you don't need to `group by` on `dept.name` because it's fully dependent on `dept.id`.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat